# server errors with documents in SharePoint server 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, search-results, owa

I am using SharePoint Server 2013 and I am facing some issues with opening the documents:

- When I created a new Office file (Excel, word...) I received server error:

[image: Create online documents error]

- when I opened the documents directly from a document library, I can do that normally. But, when I did a search and opened the document I received an error:

[image: Open documents after search error]

- I cannot preview the document as shown below :

[image: Preview document error]

I did my researches and I think it's an Office Web Apps problem. I don't know even if it is installed or not since I am not the one who did the installation!!

Can someone help me?

I need to know how to check if the OWA is installed or not and if I need to install it and link it to SP

Comment: You can use `Get-SPWOPIBinding` on the server to at least identify the FQDN used to connect to WAC. You can then trace that back to the server which is running WAC. Note that WAC cannot be installed on a SharePoint server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OfficeWebApps (OWA) always need to be installed on a separate Server. So we first have to find out where it is installed.

- Execute `Get-SPWopiBinding` in a SharePoint Management Shell on your SharePoint Server. You will find your OWA-Hostname in the attribute `ServerName`
- Execute `Get-SPWopiZone`. Note the protocol (HTTP or HTTPS)
- Then connect to your OWA-Server, start a PowerShell as Administrator and enter `Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm`. This will display your OWA-Configuration.
- Make sure, that the hostname in `Internal URL` matches the `ServerName` on your SharePoint WOPI-Binding. Please note that `ServerName` only shows a Hostname, no protocol (like HTTP oder HTTPS). This is OK! The Protocol must match the value of your `WOPIZone`.

Please post some screenshots if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MHeld ! I got the Server Name and the http protocol. However when I tried to connect to the OWA-Server using **Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm** , I got an error saying that the term Get- OfficeWebAppsFarm is not recognized as the name of the cmdlets. I tried to import the OWA module using **Import-Module -Name OfficeWebApps**   but I got another error  saying that the specified module was not loaded because no valid module file was found. I am sorry I couldn't insert the screenshots in the comment so you can understand my issues!

Comment: Please make sure to execute the Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm on your OWA-Server, not on SharePoint. If you get the error on your OWA-Server, it seems that the product is no longer installed. You can check this in Installed Programs and features.

Comment: Thanks @MHeld I will check and get back to you! I just want you to know that I tried **http://ServerName/hosting/discovery** and I got  **Server Error We're sorry. An error has occurred. We've logged the error for the server administrator**

Comment: I found the server on which the OWA is installed. But Should I execute the **Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm** on the windows powershell ? What about uninstalling it and reinstall it and start the configuration from scratch?

Comment: Yes, Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm is a OfficeWebApps CMDlet. So please execute it on your OWA-Server and post the output. My recommendation depends on that. Thanks!

Comment: this is what I get when I executed the cmdlt: **it does not appear that this machine is part of an office web apps server farm**. I think I need to rebuilt the farm. Give your thoughts @MHeld please! Thanks

Comment: Your OWA-Binaries seem to be installed. You need to create a new farm with the New-OfficeWebAppsFarm cmdlet.

Comment: Thank you for your patience @MHeld ! Is it necessary to have a certificate for the OWA?  I executed **New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalURL http://servername -EditingEnabled **  and I got **your current configuration requires a certificate name**. Should I buy it from Microsoft or generate it from the Server certificate in the IIS?

Comment: It is recommended to use HTTPS with a OfficeWebApps environment. But i see tons of implementations working with HTTP. Please check config on your SP-Server with Get-SPWopiZone and Get-SPWopiBinding and post output here. You should also read these two articles: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219455.aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx.

Comment: The WopiZone is internal-http @MHeld

Comment: Then try to build an OWA-Farm with HTTP: New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalURL "http://servername" -AllowHttp -EditingEnabled

Comment: I think the best solution is to generate the WAC Certificate and create the Farm from scratch then link the OWA to SharePoint @MHeld. I tried most of the solutions, even the "New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalURL "servername" -AllowHttp -EditingEnabled" give **Setting EditedEnabled to true. You should only do this if users of Office Web Apps has licences that permit editing office web apps** I pressed Y to accept but an error is coming "The first line of the proof key file should be a lomg (Date Time as ticks) "

Comment: Troubleshooting all those issues will take more time than a fresh installation. Important: Do not install any other software than OfficeWebApps on that server! I have seen customers installing Office or SharePoint Designer and OWA was broken after that.

Comment: Thank you @MHeld I was struggling with troubleshooting the errors and then I get a new server and install the OWA from ground zero then link it to SharePoint. Now, everything is working fine!!!